# 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll using Linq and DataSet

Tags: c#, boolean, linq-to-dataset

```
bool? isSiteExists = null;
            isSiteExists = true;
            isSiteExists = false;
            isSiteExists = dtData.AsEnumerable().Any(Rowx => Value1 == Rowx.Field<string>("ColValue1"));
```

also tried this

```
        bool? isSiteExists = dtData.AsEnumerable().Any(Rowx => Value1 == Rowx.Field<string>("ColValue1"));
```

also not working

runtime error

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Value cannot be null.

As far I know the "?" is support null value.

what is the right syntax...

Comment: What is the type of `dtData`?

Comment: I bet you still get the error when you just write `dtData.AsEnumerable().Any(Rowx => Value1 == Rowx.Field<string>("ColValue1"));` without any assignment. The error does not occur because of `bool?`, but because `dtData` or `dtData.AsEnumerable()` or `RowX` are `null`.

Comment: Yes you are right... I've check DataTable dtData is null. I must fix this. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you get an `ArgumentNullException` its probably because of something went wrong getting `dtData`.

Comment: Maybe even `dtData` returns null?

Comment: If you correct that typo or whatever problem there is with `dtData` then your assignment should be 100% valid. Just make sure that your data table don't return null.

Comment: Yes you are right... I've check DataTable dtData is null. I must fix this. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like problem is not related to bool? type.

I think problem is in dtData.AsEnumerable() or may be in your lambda Rowx => Value1 == Rowx.Field("ColValue1")

Even more dtData.AsEnumerable().Any(...) will never return null. It looks like

bool Any(this IQueryable source, Expression> predicate)

If you are trying to get null for case when something is wrong you should use exception handling instead.

Answer (score 0):

The exception that you are getting isn't referring to the nullable boolean, it is being thrown by the right had side of the assignment because something in this part:

`dtData.AsEnumerable().Any(Rowx => Value1 == Rowx.Field<string>("ColValue1"));`

is null.

As the exception is being thrown in the System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll my guess would be that it came from the `AsEnumerable()` method and `dtData` is null.

You can easily check this by putting a breakpoint on the line and checking the value of `dtData` in the debugger.

Comment: Yes you are right... I've check DataTable dtData is null. I must fix this. Thanks for your help.